# Knockout.js SimpleGrid doesn't render correctly

Tags: javascript, datagrid, hyperlink, knockout.js, kogrid

I was trying to modify [Knockout.js simpleGrid](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QSRBR/) , so that I could put hyperlink in cell content. I replaced

```
 this.addItem = function() {
    this.items.push({ name: "New item", sales: 0, price: 100 });
};
```

with

```
 this.addItem = function() {
    this.items.push({ name: "<a href='#'> click me </a>", sales: 0, price: 100 });
};
```

hoping, that after hitting "Add item" button, a new item would appear, with link in it's name. Unfortunately, it rendered as pure text and I got this in new item's name

```
 <a href='#'>click me</a>
```

So, can anybody help with this? I want to put a hyperlink inside grid cell

Answer (score 2):

The template in the simpleGrid plugin uses the `text` binding on the `td`.  This will set the `innerText` of the cell, so any HTML content would be escaped.

You would have modify the template (called "ko_simpleGrid_grid") in the simple grid plugin to either use the `html` binding rather than `text` or to actually render specific content that you want.

Comment: how to add it? Is there any example for it. I also need this now